# Fluid Dynamics (Air) Specifically Aeronautics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft

An airplane lifts off when the pressure of air pushing down on the wing is reduced due to the speed of the vehicle.

Would it be possible to construct an airplane so heavy that it would be totally impossible for it to ever get off the ground?

Comment: It takes very exacting engineering to design a craft that WILL get off the ground.

Comment: Suppose you increase the wing loading by making the wings really small, like if you reduce their dimension by 1/2, you reduce their area by 1/4 (quadrupling the wing loading). Well, you could compensate for that by making the wind over the wings really fast, like if you double the speed, you quadruple the lift. So no, I don't think you can construct such an airplane, as long as there's no limit on speed.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey At some point compressibility will make acceleration harder, and beyond that heating. The airplane will melt before it lifts off. If we restrict density to realistic values, I expect it will fly before it melts, but only at supersonic speed.

Answer (score 1):

of course, but to do so would represent a catastrophic design error. Far more likely from the standpoint of the history of flight is when an airplane is designed to use a certain engine to get it off the ground, and then the engine does not put out the intended power that the aircraft designers were counting on- so the aircraft cannot carry its intended payload, or cannot achieve its intended design altitude, or its intended airspeed.